# React state is not updated

Tags: reactjs, state

I'm new to react. My problem is that after the fetch the state of allCards is being changed but not the state of currentCard and showCard.

```
 const [showCard, setShowCard] = useState(false)

  const [allCards, setallCards] = useState<CardProp[]>([]);
  const [currentCard, setcurrentCard] = useState<CardProp>();

  function getRandomCard() {
    return allCards[Math.floor(Math.random() * allCards.length)];
  }
  function updateCard() {
    setcurrentCard(getRandomCard());
  }

  const fetchCards = async () => {
    const cardRequest = await fetch("/api/card", {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: token!,
      },
    });
    console.log(cardRequest);
    if (cardRequest.status === 200) {
      const cardJSON = await cardRequest.json();
      setallCards(cardJSON.cards);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchCards();

    if (allCards.length > 0) {
      setcurrentCard(getRandomCard());
      setShowCard(true);
    }
  }, []);
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have 2 use effects to do the updates as follows.

For initial rendering, to fetch cards

```
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchCards();
  }, []);
```

To update current cards

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (allCards.length > 0) {
      setcurrentCard(getRandomCard());
      setShowCard(true);
    }
  }, [allCards]);
```

Comment: You may want to also explain why the OP's code is not working by linking to: [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54069253/6367213)

Answer (score 0):

Because `fetchCards` is `asynchronous` so `if` condition will not run in the componentDidMount (the initial of `allCards` is `[]`)

You should put this logic in the other `useEffect` with dependencies is `allCards`. It will run when `allCards` was update after fetch success.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (allCards.length > 0) {
    setcurrentCard(getRandomCard());
    setShowCard(true);
  }
}, [allCards]);
```

Comment: The OP is using a *functional* component. There's no `componentDidMount`.

Comment: useEffect with empty dependences as componentDidMount.

Comment: It makes no difference whether `fetchCards` is asynchronous  or not in this case.

Answer (score -1):

Your `fetchCards()` is an asyncronous method. Also, setState in ansynchronous.You can use additional `useEffect` with a dependency in like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
      fetchCards();
 }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
     if (allCards.length > 0) {
       setcurrentCard(getRandomCard());
       setShowCard(true);
     }
  }, [allCards]);
```

You have two `useEffect`, one with empty array for componentDidMount, and one another to react to change of allCards

Comment: I don't mean to be rude but your first solution doesn't work and the second one is a copy paste from the accepted answer. You may want to consider deleting your answer.